# Using Gesture Recognizers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uigesturerecognizer

Before you respond, keep in mind I am very new to swift (last time I coded was 2 years ago and that was OBJC), and I seem to be having an error. Here's a sample of my code:

```
init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>) {
    originView = sourceView
    sideBarTableViewController.tableData = menuItems

    animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: originView)
    let showGestureRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
    showGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    originView.addGestureRecognizer(showGestureRecognizer)
    let hideGestureRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
}
```

I seem to be having errors  with the UISwipeGestureRecognizer target. I can't set it to self, because it gives me this error: 'self' used before super.init call.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You would have been helped by reading my new Swift tutorial: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_class_initializers It explains the rules for what you must do in an `init`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's linked to the gesture recognisers. Try to modify your Init() method, by adding at the  beginning (inside):

```
super.init()
```

This will initialize the object with the parameters of the class you are overriding. Also it will probably ask you to add `override` before your init method.

Comment: Thanks, just added this to the top of my code, and now it works flawlessly. Thanks for the quick response!